# Call service from plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, service, groovy

Can we call service from a plugin? For example I have a plugin, it has its own domain, so now can we call the service of the main application from this domain ?

Comment: If it requires functionality in the application, it kind of defeats the purpose of it being a plugin.

Comment: actually i am trying to edit an existing plugin.

Comment: Why not then just copy out the functionality you want into your own application?

Comment: This would call for a massive refactor of my code. I am just looking for a quick fix. I just need to use 'grailsApplication' on my domain of plugin, when I try to inject 'grailsApplication' on the plugin's domain and try to use it, it throws a null pointer exception !

Answer (score 0):

You can inject it yourself in Bootstrap.groovy, as all is initialized at that time.
Maybe better approach would be to autowire it with something like:

```
def ctx = grailsApplication.mainContext
ctx.beanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(instance, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_NAME, false)
```

Where instance is some object from the plugin.

Another approach is to use Bean PostProcessors http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/tag/bean-post-processing/

Also I really recommend "Programming Grails" book, where you can read about such problems and how to resolve them.